# Android Browser: Does it open up automatically for NFC tags?

Tags: android, nfc

Assuming there are no other NFC apps installed, would an Android 2.3.3 device automatically open up the Android browser if a user taps an NFC tag containing a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would open the pre-installed Tags application. This will show the URL, and if you "click" on the URL, it will open the browser (or any other application you have configured for handling URL's).